# Get array from JSON string

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, regex

I have a string that is a JSON object. This JSON object can have multiple arrays in it. It can be nested as well. I'd like to only get those arrays. For example:

```
"{x: {y: [2,3]}, t: [3,5]}"
```

Becomes:

```
[[2,3], [3,5]]
```

Is there a way to use something like regular expressions to do this?

Comment: "*I have a string that is a JSON object.*" – No, you don't. [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) has a strict syntax which your example does not comply with. Instead of dealing with Regex to parse it, you should rather fix the source to emit actual JSON and than use `JSON.parse`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `reviver` function from [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

```js
const json = '{"x": {"y": [2,3]}, "t": [3,5]}'

const arrays = []
const parsed = JSON.parse(json, (k, v) => 
  Array.isArray(v) ? (arrays.push(v), v) : v
)

console.log(arrays)
```